# Accessing local servers across network routers

Tags: networking, router, host

I have recently added a dlink router to my existing network, and connected some computers with it. The existing network uses ip range 192.168.1.x and the new router uses 192.168.0.x. Internet services is accessible on both the networks, but a shared resource or a web server connected to one network is not accessible to the systems of other network.

I googled this issue but I am unable to resolve the issue, please help.

Comment: Not a [so] question. Ask on [su]

Comment: was not aware of this, will take care of it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just going to be using the router as a switch on an existing network, you need to turn off its router-y features.

Go onto the web interface of the device and turn of "NAT", that way they'll use the same address space as everything else on the network.

They'll be other features as well you may want to turn off but that's one causing your current issue.

Comment: works as a charm, thank you!